# how to keep in the same cell after refeshing the datagridview c#

Tags: c#, sql

i use timer for refreshing datagridview. pls help me
every 10 secs the datagridview refresh . i can't find code where after refreshing or sorti g the datagridview the selected cell will remain pls help me..

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
        {  
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT (Cust_No) as [Customer ID],(Cust_surname) as [Surname], (Cust_fname) as [First Name], (Cust_mi) as [Middle Initial],  (Cust_address) as [Address], (Cust_ContactNO) as [Contact Number], (Cust_Faxno) as [Fax Number], (Cust_Tin)as [TIN]  FROM Customer WHERE cust_status like ('Active')");
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            ds = new DataSet("ds");
            da.Fill(ds);
            ds.Tables[0].TableName = "table_mirror";
            dataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables["table_mirror"];

        }
        else
        {
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT (comp_no) as [Company ID],(comp_name) as [Company Name], (comp_contactperson) as [Contact Person], (comp_address) as [Address],  (comp_contactno) as [Contact No], (comp_fax) as [Fax], (comp_Tin) as [Tin] FROM Company WHERE comp_status like ('Active')");
            cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd1.Connection = conn;
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
            ds = new DataSet("ds");
            da.Fill(ds);
            ds.Tables[0].TableName = "table_mirror";
            dataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables["table_mirror"];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this help u.

```
        Point[] oldSelectedCells = new Point[dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count; i++)
        {
            oldSelectedCells[i].X = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[i].ColumnIndex;
            oldSelectedCells[i].Y = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[i].RowIndex;
        }

        // refresh datagridview

        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;
        foreach (Point p in oldSelectedCells)
            dataGridView1[p.X, p.Y].Selected = true;
```